# How to alter error message of invalid enum type message in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling

I have several enum types for different tables. The database is accessed by a frontend software, where the user needs to fill out forms. If an user enters a wrong value in such an enum-typed column he will get the following error message:

```
"invalid input value for enum ..."
```

How can I change this error message with my own user-friendly error message, e.g. something like

```
"An error occured for field A! Only values 'yes' or 'no' are allowed for this field"
```

Comment: How about catching the error/exception and produce your own?  (This is definitely not a full answer - but then your question is lacking details, too.)

Comment: I think that's something you're going to have to do client-side? It might also be easier for coding if you were to use small reference tables instead of enums?

Comment: @dezso I dpn't know where to start with the catching of the error. Should I do this in a trigger? The frontend is the geospatial software QGIS where I include database views, which again can be edited by the user with defined privileges.